# Using VLC Terminal Commands In Python Behaves Differently In IDLE Vs. Terminal

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to write a jukebox code that will allow a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian to boot to the terminal and run my script instead of booting to the desktop.  The Pi will be running in a blind mode without a screen, only showing typed digits from a matrix keypad on a 4-digit 7-segment display.

When I'm writing and testing the code from the desktop and run my program in IDLE it works great.  It prompts for 2 digits for the disc number, then 2 digits for the track number.  Then it sends a command to the terminal to use the "dummy mode" of VLC to play back an mp3.  This isn't directly from my program, but it will show the basic functionality:

```
import os

# The script asks for user input to ask for the disc and track number
discNum="01"
trackNum="01"  

# With the variable values above, this sends a command to terminal to 
# play Disc 01, Track 01 in the background
songSelection="cvlc /home/pi/JukeMP3/"+discNum+"/"+trackNum+"*.mp3 &"
os.system(songSelection)
```

This works from the desktop.  I have the input script on loop to accept an input, stop the current playing track with a "killall vlc" command, then start the selected track.  Using cvlc places VLC player in dummy mode (no window), and the "&" at the end of the command allows the program to continue running after a song starts playing.

The problem is that when I set up my script to run on boot and it runs in Terminal instead of an IDLE window VLC player outputs some information about the playing track and locks up the prompt, stopping the program from continuing.  Instead of placing the requested command into the background the "&" seems to make no difference.

Is there a way to get VLC to work in the background without taking control of the terminal so my program can continue?

Comment: Basically the difference is that running it in IDLE places the process in a background terminal window that is actually doing the same thing, but in desktop mode the program still has its own window to continue running.  In terminal only mode everything is linear.  I need to know how to run VLC in a hidden process from terminal if that is possible so it doesn't interrupt the Python program.

Comment: If it's the output of `cvlc` that's causing the problem, have you tried redirecting its `stdout` to `/dev/null`? You might also have an easier time dealing with the child process if you use a more sophisticated means of running it from Python, like one of the functions in the `subprocess` module (most of which would accept a `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL` keyword argument). `os.system` is very bare bones.

Comment: I'm still very new to both Linux and Python, so please forgive my ignorance.  If you could provide an example of that it would be awesome.